# How to eyedrop the exact color material of a plane(palette) with a mouse?

Tags: python, game-engine

I'm trying to make a script that eyedrops on a plane(palette) with various materials assigned on each faces with a mouse cursor.

[image]

Using some sort of eyedropping module would only get me different color values instead; not the same one the materials I assigned. I'm guessing of how it is rendered on runtime.

Comment: Is using a UV map with mesh scaled to 0 an option?

Comment: Here's a color-pick example for BGE: https://github.com/mikepan/GameEngineBook/blob/master/text/07-Scripting.md#Example_02_Color_Picker

Comment: @REMCodes no. It's a plane with four faces and each faces had different materials assigned

Comment: @RPaladin thank you, I'll look into it

Comment: @RPaladin EDIT: thank you, that's exactly what I'm looking for :D

Comment: Glad I could help. I reposted my comment from above as a thread solution. Could you mark it as the thread answer to notify others that this thread has already been solved? Thanks.

Comment: @RPaladin No problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Retweeting from comments.

Here's a color-pick for BGE:

https://github.com/mikepan/GameEngineBook/blob/master/text/07-Scripting.md#Example_02_Color_Picker